# Finite part integral for terms involving absolute value

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, regularization

Can the simple "recipe" for [Cauchy principle value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) and [Hadamard Finite Part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization) be extended to find the finite part of integrals of the form $$\int_a^b f\big(\left|x-c\right|\big) \ dx$$ with $c \in [a,b]$ and $f(\left|x\right|) \sim \frac{1}{\left|x\right|} \ x \to 0$?

The most obvious extension seems to be $$\int_a^b f(\left|x-c\right|) \ dx = \int_a^{c-\epsilon} f\big(\left|x-c\right|\big) \ dx + \int_{c+\epsilon}^b f\big(\left|x-c\right|\big) \ dx + 2 \log{\epsilon} \lim_{x->c}\big(f\big(\left|x-c\right|\big)\left|x-c\right|\big) $$
but I'm not convinced that this 'recipe' can be justified by meromorphic continuation the way that the Hadamard case can. I don't know of any way to apply contour integration here due to the absolute value.